Fast(est) way to process an expanding linear sequence in Python
I have the following conditions:

The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u also.
There are no other numbers in u.
No duplicates should be present.
The numbers must be in ascending sequential order

Ex: u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]
The program wants me to give the value of a member at a given index.
I've already found ways to solve this using insort and I hacked together a minimal binary search tree, as well. Unfortunately, this process needs to be faster than what I have and I'm at a loss as to what to do next. I thought the BST would do it, but it is not fast enough.
Here's my BST code:
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = val

    def insert(self, val):
        if not self.val:
            self.val = val
            return

        if self.val == val:
            return

        if val < self.val:
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(val)
                return
            self.left = BSTNode(val)
            return

        if self.right:
            self.right.insert(val)
            return
        self.right = BSTNode(val)

    def inorder(self, vals):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.inorder(vals)
        if self.val is not None:
            vals.append(self.val)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.inorder(vals)
        return vals

and here's my function:
from sys import setrecursionlimit

def twotimeslinear(n):
    #setrecursionlimit(2000)
    i = 0
    u = [1]
    ended = False

    bst = BSTNode()
    bst.insert(1)
    while i < n and not ended:
        
        for j in range(2, 4):
            k = 1
            cur = j * bst.inorder([])[i] + 1
            bst.insert(cur)
            
            if len(u) == n:
                ended = True
                break
        i+= 1
    return bst.inorder([])[n]

I just need directions as to what I could do to make the process faster. I can solve the problem if I only knew what I was missing. I'm probably overlooking some data structure that would work better, but I don't even know what to look for. Thank you for any help.

What you describe is not a sequence (even if sometimes you use sequence vocabulary, like u(0)=1, but simply a set). If it were a sequence, we would know in which order to compute them. And you didn't say.

Thank you; adding clarification to question.

It has infinite length. So do you need to write an infinite generator or so?

I'll add clarification to the question. The program just wants the value of a number at a given index.

Sounds like a job for a heap, or sortedcontainers.SortedList.

Oh, wait, you only need to compute a single element. Generating everything up to that point is going to be way too slow, then, no matter what kind of data structure you use.

How large might the index be, and how much time is allowed?

It's for a challenge and the final test is 60000 elements, I believe.

Ah, crap, I didn't consider having to figure out the Nth mathematically without traversing it. I thought I'd get through this with minimal calculus. This helps a lot.

If it's just 60000, then computing every element should be fine. Usually these kinds of challenges have you computing up to something like the billionth element.

This sequence can be found in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/A002977

Check my edited answer

Generating and merging the ys and zs:
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

def twotimeslinear(n):
    u = [1]
    ys = (2*x+1 for x in u)
    zs = (3*x+1 for x in u)
    for x, _ in groupby(merge(ys, zs)):
        u.append(x)
        if n < len(u):
            return u[n]

print(*map(twotimeslinear, range(20)))

Attempt This Online!
Takes ~0.05 seconds for your limit index 60,000 and ~0.7 seconds for index 1,000,000.
Alternative basic implementation:
def twotimeslinear(n):
    u = [1]
    i = j = 0
    while n >= len(u):
        y = 2*u[i] + 1
        z = 3*u[j] + 1
        m = min(y, z)
        u.append(m)
        if y == m:
            i += 1
        if z == m:
            j += 1
    return u[n]

print(*map(twotimeslinear, range(20)))

Attempt This Online!
And another version, throwing tons of batteries at it :-)
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby, tee, chain, islice, repeat
from operator import itemgetter, mul, add

def twotimeslinear(n):
    parts = [[1]]
    whole = chain.from_iterable(parts)
    output, feedback1, feedback2 = tee(whole, 3)
    ys = map(1 .__add__, map(2 .__mul__, feedback1))
    zs = map(add, map(mul, repeat(3), feedback2), repeat(1))  # different way just for fun
    merged = map(itemgetter(0), groupby(merge(ys, zs)))
    parts.append(merged)
    return next(islice(output, n, None))

print(*map(twotimeslinear, range(20)))

After setting it up with Python code, this runs entirely in C code. It's a silly hobby of mine.
Attempt This Online!

Thank you. This worked perfectly. I wish I could've figured this out, but I'm nowhere near familiar with the Python standard library yet

@ep84 Meh, it's not really about the library but about the algorithm. I added a more basic version.

@ep84 But now I also went the opposite direction and added a version using an unhealthy amount of library usage...

Amazing work. I don't mean to minimize the amount of skill it takes to think algorithmically like that. I can only hope to keep getting better.

you really shouldn't use 1 .__add_ and 2.__mul__ directly. use operator and functools.partial or a lambda expression

@juanpa.arrivillaga Why? All values are ints, your usual concern of type issues doesn't apply.
